# How to request movie data from http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/ for my android application

Tags: android

im on my way to creating mobile app to search movies from apiary
How to request movie data from http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/ for my nadroid application?
Can anyone help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    private static final String API_KEY = "XXX"; 

    // the number of movies you want to get in a single request to their web server
    private static final int MOVIE_PAGE_LIMIT = 10; 

    private EditText searchBox;
    private Button searchButton;
    private ListView moviesList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_search_box);
        searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_search);
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            // send an API request when the button is pressed
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                new RequestTask().execute("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?" + API_KEY + "&q=" + searchBox.getText().toString().trim() + "&page_limit=" + MOVIE_PAGE_LIMIT);
            }
        });
        moviesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_movies);
    }

    private void refreshMoviesList(String[] movieTitles)
    {
        moviesList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, movieTitles));
    }

    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is how you use your API_KEY.
It should be:

```
new RequestTask().execute("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + API_KEY + "&q=" + searchBox.getText().toString().trim() + "&page_limit=" + MOVIE_PAGE_LIMIT);
```